# What Event Happens After Loaded For A WPF UserControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, events, datagrid

I have a DataGrid, which I bind in the constructor function of my UserControl (after InitializeComponent).  I need to access some rows in it, so in the loaded event for the UserControl, I run:

```
DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)myDataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(rowIdx);
```

However whenever I do that, ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex returns null.  Seemed like the DataGrid wasn't fully generated yet, so to test/confirm that theory, I threw a button on the screen, and on the click event of the button, I ran that code again, and then sure enough, the row had a value.  So, it's confirmed, when the UserControl's loaded event fires, it happens too early and I can't yet call ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex for my DataGrid.

What event gets fired after loaded that I could use instead?

**Note**: I also tried this code that I found, but got the same results:

```
DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)myDataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(rowIdx);
if (row == null)
{
    myDataGrid.UpdateLayout();
    myDataGrid.ScrollIntoView(myDataGrid.Items[rowIdx]);
    row = (DataGridRow)myDataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(rowIdx);
}
```

And I also tried doing it in the DataGrid's loaded event but same results.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks everyone!  This ended up doing the trick:

```
myDataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged += new EventHandler(ItemContainerGenerator_StatusChanged);
:
:
void ItemContainerGenerator_StatusChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (myDataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.Status == GeneratorStatus.ContainersGenerated)
    {
        DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)myDataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(rowIdx);
        if (row == null)
        {
            myDataGrid.UpdateLayout();
            myDataGrid.ScrollIntoView(myDataGrid.Items[rowIdx]);
            row = (DataGridRow)myDataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(rowIdx);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can run that code at a lower [DispatcherPriority](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherpriority.aspx) than Loaded, such as `Input`

For example, the DataGrid's `Loaded` event would contain something that looks like this:

```
MyDataGrid.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Input,
    new Action(delegate() { RunSomeFunction(); } ));
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks according to this [article](http://stuff.seans.com/2008/07/16/hello-wpf-world-part-3-forms-and-windows/) that the last event on a new form would be the ContentRendered event.
But it looks like from this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2006/09/19/loadedvsinitialized.aspx), for the usercontrol the last event would be the Loaded event.

You might try setting a timer with a small delay at the end of your loaded event to run your code   in order to get some seperation.